# A riddle for great minds

Tags: riddle

> You pay for me to work, but you would rather I just hang around and do nothing. What am I?

My first guess was a loan. What do you think is the answer?

Answer (score 7):

I feel that this may be too broad but my first thought was a

> Smoke alarm

Reasoning

> It's something you need to work but usually you don't want it to. Plus, it hangs from the ceiling.

Comment: I agree this question is waaay too broad. My first thought was very similar to yours - a rot13(Ohetyne nynez). There are all kinds of similar objects that satisfy the riddle in the same way... :)

Comment: rot13(Va guvf yvar bs gubhtug, creuncf nyfb n ohetyne nynez)

Answer (score 4):

First thing that comes to mind is

> Life Insurance

Reasoning

> You would rather just pay premiums than to die for it to work

Comment: I like this answer.  rot13(Ernyyl nal xvaq bs vafhenapr - V cnl sbe zl nhgb vafhenapr, ohg V qba'g jnag gb trg va n penfu)

Answer (score 2):

Deliberately stretching here a bit just for fun, but how about

> The mayor's nephew.  You hired him to get in good with the mayor, but he's in no way qualified to do the work.  So best case he hangs around and does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This may also be

> a gun

Explanation:

> If you buy one for self-defence, you would prefer to have it just hanging on your mantelpiece without ever needing to fire it, but if you ever *do* need to fire it, you would hope that it works.